# Determine all roots of $\sinh(z^2) = \dfrac{15}{8}$

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-functions

> $\sinh \left(z^2\right)=\frac{15}{8}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Let } z=x+jy, \quad j^2 = -1 \\
& \frac{e^{z^2}-e^{-z^2}}{2}=\frac{15}{8} \\
& e^{z^2}-\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}=\frac{15}{4} \\
& A-\frac{1}{A}=\frac{15}{4} \\
& 4A^2-15A-4=0 \\
& (4A+1)(A-4)=0 \\
& A=4,-\frac{1}{4}, \text{ where } A = e^{z^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

> $\mathbf{I}. e^{z^2} = 4$

$$\begin{aligned} 
&\text{from } z=x+j y
\end{aligned}$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \therefore z^2=x^2-y^2+j 2 x y \\
e^{\left(x^2-y^2\right)+2 j x y} & =4 \\
e^{\left(x^2-y^2\right)} e^{2 x y j} & =4 e^{j(0+2 n \pi)} \\
\therefore e^{x^2-y^2}=4 & , 2 x y=2 n \pi
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x^2-y^2=\ln 4, \quad x y=n \pi \\
& x^2 y^2=n^2 \pi^2 \\
& \left(y^2+\ln 4\right) y^2=n^2 \pi^2 \\
& y^4+(\ln 4 )y^2=n^2 \pi^2 \\
& y^2=\frac{-\ln 4 \pm \sqrt{\ln ^2 4+4 n^2 \pi^2}}{2} \\
& \because y^2>0 ; y^2=\frac{\sqrt{\ln ^2 4+4 n^2 \pi^2}-\ln 4}{2} \\
& y^2=\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2 \\
& y= \pm \sqrt{ \sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2 }\\
& x^2=y^2+\ln 4=\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}+\ln 2 \\
& x= \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}+\ln 2} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
$\because x y=n\pi$ 
when $n=0 \rightarrow y=0$ and $x= \pm \sqrt{\ln 4} \rightarrow z= \pm \sqrt{\ln{4}}$ 

when $n>0 \rightarrow\{x>0, y>0]$ or $[x<0, y<0\} ; z= \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}+\ln 2} \pm j \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2}$ 

when $n<0 \rightarrow[x<0, y>0]$ or $[x>0, y<0] ; z= \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}+\ln 2} \mp j \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+n^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2}$

---

> $\mathbb{II}. \quad e^{z^2} = -\dfrac{1}{4}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& e^{x^2-y^2} = \ln{\frac{1}{4}} \text{ , } e^{2 x y j}=\frac{1}{4} e^{j(\pi+2 n \pi)} \\
& e^{x^2-y^2} = \ln \left(\frac{1}{4}\right), \quad 2 x y=(2 n+1) \pi \\
& x^2-y^2=-\ln 4, x y=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi \\
& x^2=y^2-\ln 4 \\
& x^2 y^2=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2 \\
& y^2\left(y^2-\ln 4\right)=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2 \\
& y^4-(\ln 4 )y^2=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2 \\
& y^2=\frac{\ln 4 \pm \sqrt{\ln ^2 4+4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}}{2} \\
\because y^2 \geqslant 0 \\
& y^2=\ln 2+\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(0+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2} \\
& y= \pm \sqrt{\ln 2+\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}}\\ 
& x^2=y^2-\ln 4 \\
& =\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2 \\
& x= \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2} \\
& \begin{array}{l}
\text { when } n \geqslant 0 \rightarrow x y \geqslant 0 \\
z = x+j y= \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}-\ln 2} \pm j \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}+\ln 2}
\end{array} \\
& \text { when } n<0 \rightarrow x y<0 \\
& z=x+j y= \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2-}\ln 2} \mp j \sqrt{\sqrt{\ln ^2 2+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \pi^2}+\ln 2} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Is there any point I do wrong? I’m not sure. I wonder if there’s other method easier than I do.

[Here's my work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJJLY.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your working in your post. [Here is a reference guide to typeset your maths](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The document you link to is too small to be readable.

Comment: I have edited the question as per the picture. I have left the link of the picture incase I made a mistake. Feel welcome to correct!

Comment: Thank you! I corrected it all now.